# with firefox w/firebug, how can I write javascript in the browser and use the .js file objects also?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

With firefox w/firebug, can I type javascript into the browser and test things?

Can I also reference functions/objects from .js files references in the html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you can, by using the console.

Longer answer: Take a look at the [What's new in Firebug 1.6 video](http://vimeo.com/18411877), it gives an excellent demonstration on what you can do with the console, including auto-completion of the available variables.

Everything that's available globally in the current document is available to the console. So if you included jQuery on the current page, it'll be accessible from the console too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you enable the console tab you can use it as a Javascript [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop). From there you should be able to access any variables and objects in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can... while on firebug (1.6.1) click 5th button from the left, its like a bunch of lines, entitled **show command line** then you will see it.

as for your second question... u can use it as long as it is on the DOM otherwise goodluck to u :)